# Still able to access url even after server stopped?

Tags: java, linux, websphere, war

We have stopped server explicitly "server stop servername".

In messages.log we have observed the statement as server stopped. But url is still accessible. Earlier it worked fine. i.e. when we stopped the server, server was getting down and we were not able to access url.

It is Websphere , OS: Linux.

Please suggest the cause for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would first ensure that the server is stopped by checking that the java process is no longer running.

Once that's confirmed, I would try to access the URL from a private/incognito browser window to ensure it's not due to caching.

If it still comes up, I would check to see if there's another server around hosting that same servlet that the request is being routed to.

Comment: thanks @M Broz   , the issue is we have some proxy server that is holding the home page of server, so whenever we hit the url we are getting the response from proxy server instead of application server. thats why we  are able to see the page even the application server is down